# Showing background image only on first page

Tags: jquery, ajax, background-image

-edited for clarity-

I have an index-page with a DIV, into which other main content (html-files) gets loaded (client-side) when the visitor clicks on a link (via AJAX, jquery load(), see code below).

I want to add a random background-image, ONLY on the initially loading page (i.e. in the body-tag), but as soon as some (other) content gets loaded into the "ajax" DIV, this background-image should disappear from body of index.html.

I would like to write an if-else condition which makes sure the content of that "ajax" DIV is still unchanged. 
I found `window.location.href`does not work to check the state of the site, as the resulting URL is always the same, independent of the AJAX loaded content.

Now, would there be a way to write a condition like:

*- IF original DIV-content gets exchanged, => background : ' '*

or

*- IF DIV-content has/hasn't ID..., => background : ' '*

I hope my problem can be understood.

---

**EDIT**: I add something which I hope helps a bit for clarification:
my site (index.html), simplyfied, looks like this:

```
<head>  
</head>
<body>
    <a class="ajaxLink" href="othercontent.html">next</a>

        <div id="content-main">
            <div id="othercontent"></div> //<== this is content from other html-file
        </div>
</body>
```

The User clicks on the link, and then, using jquery load(), **some html-file content gets loaded into the div (#content-main)**, and in the end everything only happens in this single index.html.
So if I assign a background-image to the body of the index.html (using jquery $('body').css...), **I need to find a way to identify when non-initial content exists/gets loaded in the DIV #content-main**..

---

**EDIT2**:
I will now paste the mentioned jQuery code here, as it should help to understand why some suggestion from the answers do not work (don't get confused, the code contains both the ajax load() for new content, AND many lines for HTML5 history functionality):

```
$(function () {
//AJAX: load html-pages dynamically into this site's div (#content-main), and add browser history and URL support

    /*unnecessary? I don't use the next 3 lines of code
    //To override the default action for the link(anchor tag), use the following jQuery code snippet.
    $("a.ajaxLink").on('click', function (e) {
        //code for the link action
        return false;
    });
    */

    //Now to get the ajax content and display it and change the browser URL to the specific location without refresh use the following code.
    $("a.ajaxLink").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        /*
        - if uncomment the ABOVE line, html5 nonsupported browers won't change the url but will display the ajax content;
        - if commented, html5 nonsupported browers will reload the page to the specified link.
        */

        //get the link location that was clicked
        pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

        //to get the ajax content and display in div #content-main
        $('#content-main').load(pageurl+'?rel=tab'+'#content-main');

        //to change the browser URL to the given link location
        if(pageurl!=window.location){
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
        }
        //stop refreshing to the page given in
        return false;
    });

    //the below code is to override back button to get the ajax content without page reload
    //added some details from http://rosspenman.com/pushstate-jquery/ - otherwise going back in history to initial page resulted in issues
    $(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.state !== null) {
            $('#content-main').load(location.pathname+'?rel=tab'+'#content-main');
        }
        else {
            $('body').load(location.pathname+'?rel=tab'+'#content-main');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Try passing another parameter to the ajax call and only return the background if it is the index page. This paraeter could be the div id or some global variable indicating it is in the index.

Comment: Ok, that was one idea I just had, but I think I'm not good enough to know how I would do that: let's say, there's always this one DIV, but I know that I only want background if the sub-DIV in the ajax-DIV has not ID #othercontent.. any hint how to do that?

Comment: ..like IF(#ajax contains #othercontent) do nothing ELSE $('body').css({'background-image': ....});

Comment: @JWatan " I want to add a random background image, ONLY on the initially loading page" "but I know that I only want background if the sub-DIV in the ajax-DIV has not ID #othercontent.. any hint how to do that?" Please clarify requirement ? Thanks for sharing

Comment: I added some more detailled explanation above, sorry for confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following hawaii's post

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").css("backgroundImage", "url(backgroundImageUrl)");
  $.ajax().done(function() {
    return $("body").css("backgroundImage", "");
  });
});
```

Edit

> *EDIT: I add something which I hope helps a bit for clarification: my site (index.html), simplyfied, looks like this:
>       
>       
>       
>           next
>
> ```
>         <div id="content-main">
>             <div id="othercontent"></div> //<== this is content from other html-file
>         </div>
> </body> The User clicks on the link, and then ,using jquery load(), some html-file content gets loaded into the div
> ```
>
> (#content-main), and in the end everything only happens in this single
>   index.html. So if I assign a background img to the body of the
>   index.html (using jquery $('body').css...), I need to find a way to
>   identify when other content exists in the DIV #content-main..*
>
> hmm, this does not work. When I click on a link on my page, the DIV
>   get's filled with new content, but as I'm still on the index.html, the
>   body background does not change. –  JWatan

`.ready()` appears fires "once". See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

At original post , 1st paragraph

> **ONLY on the initially loading page** (i.e. in the body-tag), but as soon
>   as some (other) content gets loaded into that "ajax" DIV, this
>   background should disappear from index.html. – JWatan

`body`'s css `backgroundImage` property should only be called "once". As described at 1st paragraph of question, the entire page does not appear to "reload", only a `descendant` of `body` element, that is, `div`.

An `if` statement is not necessarily needed to check the content of the dynamically populated `div` (`descendant` of `body`). It *could* be included, but is not necessary, needed to fulfill the requirement, of the `body` element's `backgroundImage` addition or removal.

The above piece should work to fulfill the original requirement, without including further tests

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/t6ZYf/

If requirement inlcudes other than loading `backgroundImage` once , please clarify ? Happy to help, if able

Note

The `.done()` http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/ should be called after the completed `$.ajax()` request.

**Edit** (updated to reflect original question revisions https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22673564/revisions)

```
$(function () { /* `document` `ready` */
  $("body").css("backgroundImage", "url(backgroundImageUrl)"); /* set css`backgroundImage` property for `body` "once", at `document` `ready`, "initial page load", please see jquery `.ready()` api.jquery.com/ready */
//AJAX: load html-pages dynamically into this site's div (#content-main), and add browser history and URL support

    /*unnecessary? I don't use the next 3 lines of code
    //To override the default action for the link(anchor tag), use the following jQuery code snippet.
    $("a.ajaxLink").on('click', function (e) {
        //code for the link action
        return false;
    });
    */

    //Now to get the ajax content and display it and change the browser URL to the specific location without refresh use the following code.
    $("a.ajaxLink").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        /*
        - if uncomment the ABOVE line, html5 nonsupported browers won't change the url but will display the ajax content;
        - if commented, html5 nonsupported browers will reload the page to the specified link.
        */

        //get the link location that was clicked
        pageurl = $(this).attr('href');

        //to get the ajax content and display in div #content-main
        $('#content-main').load(pageurl+'?rel=tab'+'#content-main', function() {
        return $("body").css("backgroundImage", ""); /* jquery `.load()` `complete` `callback`, remove `backgroundImage` from `body` */
        });

        //to change the browser URL to the given link location
        if(pageurl!=window.location){
            window.history.pushState({path:pageurl},'',pageurl);
        }
        //stop refreshing to the page given in
        return false;
    });

    //the below code is to override back button to get the ajax content without page reload
    //added some details from http://rosspenman.com/pushstate-jquery/ - otherwise going back in history to initial page resulted in issues
    $(window).on('popstate', function(e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.state !== null) {
            $('#content-main').load(location.pathname+'?rel=tab'+'#content-main', function() {
        return ($("body").css("backgroundImage") != "" ? $("body").css("backgroundImage", "") : null); /* jquery `.load()` `complete` `callback`, `if` `backgroundImage` not empty string, remove `backgroundImage`, `else` return `null` */
        })
        }
        else { /* not certain here, if needed to achieve requirement, Try place `load()` `callback` at `if` statement above at `load()` `callback` here, as well */
            $('body').load(location.pathname+'?rel=tab'+'#content-main');
        }
    });
});
```

Note see jquery `.load()` `complete` `callback` http://api.jquery.com/load/

Hope this helps

Comment: hmm, this does not work. When I click on a link on my page, the DIV get's filled with new content, but as I'm still on the index.html, the body background does not change.

Comment: ok, I think I understand what you mean. What I have, is an initially loaded background image. I want to get rid of it.  What I now found, is, using your code, I could add the $("body")... part to each ajax-loaded html-file, which would overwrite the old background with an empty one.. but that seems to be a bit tedious..

Comment: @JWatan At initial post appeared to indicate `backgroundImage` wanted to be removed after `$.ajax()` completed ? Is that not requirement ? Not certain ? Or, `body` `backgrounImage` loaded _again_ ? Please clarify ? Thanks

Comment: no you are correct, it should be removed. But as it seems, I do not know my ajax well enough. In my initial post is a link to the code which loads the other pages into the div, there's no ajax function in it, but as I understood it uses ajax-like procedures. Maybe that is the issue, that there is no "ajax completed" at any time?

Comment: @JWatan If original requirement fulfilled , could also post separate question(s) including potentially relevant text of pieces included at / with initial (1st) post , if possible ? Not certain. Happy to help , if able, at follow-up, or other questions. If original requirement of present question met, fulfilled ? Thanks for sharing

Comment: Hi, I just re-checked. My original requierment is not fulfilled. the jQuery load() method IS indeed a AJAX method. But your suggestion (to use the $.ajax().done(function() to make sure that I loaded() some content in the specified DIV) is not working. I will add the code which loads the content to my initial post..

Comment: @JWatan Please clarify the requirement. Setting aside for a moment the main `backgroundImage` topic . Does the piece at the updated post current work ? By "work", meaning, does it _currently_ `load` content into the `content-main` `div` in the fashion desired ? Or, is debugging of the `load` and `popstate` event also necessary to meet the requirement ? Just want to be clear about all elements and  parameters of the requirement prior to updating post / prospective answer. Thanks for sharing

Comment: thanks for your patience :)  yes it does work. I'm not sure if I have everthing perfect in there, as I'm not really a developer; but it works as intended, and does also handle the "loaded()" content perfectly. If you think there are errors, maybe I should open another thread for letting s.o. review that code?  BTW edited some of the text in initial post to get rid of this misleading "first page" ...

Comment: & be informed that this jQuery code not only AJAX-loads the content, but also provides HTML5 history functionality.

Comment: @JWatan Please proceed how determine necessary. However, perhaps consider that in any field of human endeavor , if the requirement is stated as such , then changes , or changes multiple times , difficult if not impossible to ever actually affirmatively resolve the requirement. Will update post to reflect this posters' approach to original question . At own discretion, please review and accept or not accept updated post. Again, thanks for sharing, happy to help, if able, hope this helps

Comment: I'm impressed, this works. I'm sorry if I did write down misunderstandable requirements. Thank you very much for your time & effort